# How can I detect changes in queryParams and fragment simultaneously (or at least in a well-defined order)?

Tags: angular

I am writing a `WidgetList` that has query paramters (including paging data) that it reads/writes to/from the URL query parameters. But it also has a selection which it writes/reads to/from the URL fragment.

In order to facilitate this, I have subscribers to both the `queryParams` and `fragment`:

```
this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe((queryParamMap) => { handleQueryChange }
this.route.fragment.subscribe((queryParamMap) => { handleFragmentChange }
```

However, some operations on this component will cause both the pagination and selection to change at the same time (i.e. both the `queryParams` and `fragment` need to change in a single `router.navigate` call). This is proving problematic with the above subscriber model.

The logic in `handleQueryChange` and `handleFragmentChange` changes depending on whether **both** the fragment and queryParams have changed or just one of them. However, these subscribers are completely agnostic of one another so its not clear how to make this happen.

Ideally I could just subscribe to the full URL changes with something like:

```
this.route.url.subscribe((change) => {
    if (change.fragmentChanged() && change.queryParamChanged()) {
      ...
    } else if (change.fragmentChanged()) {
      ...
    } else if (change.queryParamChanged()) {
      ...
    }
}
```

In AngularJS, I would have just looked at changes in the full URL and unpacked it into the queryParams and fragment manually, but I can't find a way to do that here.

If I could see a guarantee in the docs that one of the `queryParams`/`fragment` subscribers would always execute before the other one, I could make it work.

Any solutions out there?

Comment: What's triggering the query param and fragment changes? Presumably something external to the code you have posted?

Answer (score 1):

For the Route full URL Change there are many things to look up .
Port number, Domain name, Context Path, Query Params, data, etc.

So for change of the route or when routing occurs in the page this event can be captured using the following code

```js
      this.router.events.pipe(
        filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      )
        .subscribe(() => {
          handle Navigation Changes here 
        });
```

This event will trigger when the Navigation is completed i.e NavigationEnd. There are many events of the router like Navigation Start , etc. You can check it by console logging the event.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, just try to combine fragment and params with rxjs. Something like this:

```js
queryParams$ = this.route.queryParamMap;
fragment$ = this.route.fragment;
combineLatest(this.fragment$, this.queryParams$).pipe(
  tap(([fragment,params]) => console.log('do something with:', fragment, params)),
).subscribe();
```